# Magento - adding special shipping rules?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Okay, so I am building a Magento store for a client who wants a fairly simple shipping setup, but one that I am not sure Magento supports.

She wants the customer to be billed:

5 dollars for 1 item
7 dollars for 2 items or
10 dollars for 3+ items

Is this something that can be added?  If so, how do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

If you need anything about shipping, at first you have to check WebShopApps extensions

I believe that even their free Matrix Rate allow that

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension-certified-bug-free.html

http://wiki.webshopapps.com/extensions/matrix-rates

Comment: That's good to know - thanks.  It sounds like their free version doesn't support multiple shipping methods with Paypal, which I need, but a good thing to know nevertheless.  Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible 
you have to build simple shipping module and in the collectRate Method you check how many items in the current checkout session

```
Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount();
```

and based on this you assign the amount for the shipping.

its pretty much easy straight forward module.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module

Comment: This looks great.  I need to get a bit more info from my client as well before this needs to be implemented, so I can't say for sure that I'll be able to get it done, but I suspect I will.  But I was just doing a few steps in that tutorial and now I'm having some cPanel issues - my app/etc/modules folder is showing "Data error."  Any ideas what it might be?  .htaccess is set to 644...